# Web3.version.network is 1514147182983?

Tags: web3js, testnets

Within my truffle console I'm running web3.version.network and it's returning '1514147182983'. When I check the accounts under web3, it's still connected to testrpc. How do I transition this to my testnet (Rinkeby, Ropsten, etc) accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the networks you'd like to use in `truffle.js`:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')

const mnemonic = "word1 word2 ... word12"

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' 
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://rinkeby.infura.io'),
      network_id: '*',
      gas: 4712383,
      gasPrice: 20000000000
    },
    mainnet: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://mainnet.infura.io'),
      network_id: 1,
      gas: 4500000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000
    }
  }
}
```

Set the network flag to a specified network:

```
$ truffle --network=rinkeby console
```

Get network ID in truffle console:

```
truffle(rinkeby)> web3.version.getNetwork((err, network) => console.log(network))
truffle(rinkeby)> 4
```